# Return value of SHLoadIndirectString is an errorcode

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Hi I've been trying to get name of the metro app with the acquired from AppManifest.xml of the respective app. Came to know that [SHLoadIndirectString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) could be used for this purpose. On checking its functionality manually, I couldn't get the result resource. The code snippet goes as below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <Shlwapi.h>
int main(){
    LPWSTR output = L"";
    LPWSTR input = L"@{Microsoft.BingMaps_2.1.3230.2048_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe?ms-resource://Microsoft.BingMaps/resources/AppDisplayName}";
    int result = SHLoadIndirectString(input, output, sizeof(output), NULL );
    cout<<output;
    return 0;
}
```

The return value "result" is always a negative value(changes if I am changing the input string respective to app). Please guide me on my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the right answer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include <Shlwapi.h>
int main()
{
    PWSTR output = (PWSTR) malloc(sizeof(WCHAR)*256);


    PCWSTR input = L"@{C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.BingMaps_2.1.3230.2048_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\\resources.pri?ms-resource://Microsoft.BingMaps/Resources/AppShortDisplayName}";
    int result = SHLoadIndirectString(input, output, 256, NULL );

    cout<<output;
    return 0;
}
```